# Progress notifications for http.request or fetch

Tags: nativescript

I am consuming some larger API endpoints (the returned JSON response is about 10MB).

Is there a way with http.request or fetch to get notifications about the "download" status.

Nicky

Answer (score 0):

You could use this npm package [nativescript-background-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-background-http)

Here is an example for how to track the progress:

```
var bghttp = require("nativescript-background-http");

var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");

var request = {
    url: "http://myserver.com",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
        "File-Name": "bigpig.jpg"
    },
    description: "{ 'uploading': 'bigpig.jpg' }"
};

var task = session.uploadFile("file/path/bigpig.jpg", request);

task.on("progress", logEvent);
task.on("error", logEvent);
task.on("complete", logEvent);

function logEvent(e) {
    console.log(e.eventName);
}
```

Comment: This package and the included library only supports the upload. I am looking for the download progress information.

Comment: When i go to the [api reference](http://nativescript.github.io/nativescript-background-http/globals.html) i see "Get or create a background download/upload session by id."

Comment: But the only implemented method for session is `uploadFile(..)`